# mvc routes not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have two routes in RouteConfig

```
 routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Desktop", action = "Index", wizard = "", culture = "he-IL", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Wizard",
            url: "{wizard}/{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Desktop", action = "Index", wizard = "AllManufucturer", culture = "he-IL", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I'm trying to navigate to

1. http://localhost:5754/he-IL/Account/Login which is working
2. http://localhst:5754/wizard234/he-IL/InfoRequest/Details which is not working

I tried to change the routes order and link 1 is not working and link 2 is working, I want the site will run two different routes template

Please what am I missing?

Tank you in advanced

Comment: `wizard234/he-IL/InfoRequest/Details` matches your first route - it has 4 segments

Comment: The id is optional so actually it's 3 parameters no? Anyway how I can make both routes to work?

Comment: Place default route at the end of your route config

Comment: I did it already and still just one route type is working the default one

Comment: You would need to make unique routes - e.g. `url: "{wizard}/{culture}/InfoRequest/{action}/{id}",` would be hit if it was the first route (and change `controller = "InfoRequest"`)

Comment: you have hardcoded wizard as `wizard = "AllManufucturer"`. the second url has 5 segments which falls under your "Wizard" route but fails to match wizard234, leave it blank or add another route with a blank wizard

Comment: But id is optional so it should fit no? And I moved the default to be the last route and stil not working :( And why is wizard = "AllManufucturer" makes it not work it's just default value if the parameter wizard is empty no?

Comment: Can anyone please explain how do I make a route that distinguish between wizard route and anything else?

Comment: @user3132295, Read my previous comment! You need to make them uniquely identifiable But what is the point having 2 routes anyway?

Comment: ho ok sorry I though maybe there is another way. Everything starts when I was asked to provide the ability to open the same wizard in differents tabs in the same session... I tries to implement this article [here](http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/02/17/get-a-unique-session-in-each-browser-tab/) but it's work for each request and I want it to work only on wizards...

Comment: Stephen Muecke thank you very much I made the routes unique for each wizard and everything works great!!!!! :)